# corrupted size vs. prev_size

Tags: c, sdl

SDL2を使って見たんですが、C言語は詳しくありませんでした。普通の画像描画のプログラムですが問題なく動かしました。でもプログラムを閉じた後祭には妙な文字？エラーが出ました。

閉じた後のエラー

```
$ ./main 
corrupted size vs. prev_size
Aborted
```

たまには、こういうもありました。

```
$ ./main 
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted
```

main.c

```
#include "texture.h"

int main() {
    Init();

    Texture* img;
    img = loadImage("../../Images/BGR/sky07.jpg");

    while (1) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                break;
            }
        }
        Clear();
        Draw(img);
        Display();
    }

    Destroy(img);

    Close();

    return 0;
}
```

texture.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
SDL_Event event;

typedef struct _Texture Texture;

void Init();
void Close();

void Clear();
void Display();

Texture* loadImage(const char* path);
void Draw(Texture* tex);
void Destroy(Texture* tex);
```

texture.c

```
#include "texture.h"

#define WINDOW_W 800
#define WINDOW_H 600

typedef struct _Texture {
    int x, y, w, h;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect* dst;
    SDL_Rect* src;
}Texture;

void Init() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG);
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window,
        -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC
    );
}

void Close() {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Clear() {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
}

void Display() {
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

Texture* loadImage(const char* path) {
    Texture* tex;

    tex = malloc(sizeof(Texture*));
    tex->texture = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Texture*));
    tex->dst = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect*));
    
    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(path);
    tex->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    tex->dst->x = 0;
    tex->dst->y = 0;
    tex->dst->w = surface->w;
    tex->dst->h = surface->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return tex;
}

void Draw(Texture* tex) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex->texture, NULL, tex->dst);
}

void Destroy(Texture* tex) {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex->texture);
}
```

Makefile

```
CC := gcc
LDLIBS := -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

main: main.c texture.c
```

ありがとうございました

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tex = malloc(sizeof(Texture*));`や`tex->dst = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect*));`で`Texture`や`SDL_Rect`のサイズではなく、それをを指すポインタのサイズだけメモリを確保して、

```
tex->dst->x = 0;
tex->dst->y = 0;
tex->dst->w = surface->w;
tex->dst->h = surface->h;
```

のように`Texture`や`SDL_Rect`の分だけ書き込んでいるのでメモリ破壊が起きてています。
しかし後続のデータが無いのでバグが顕在化せず、`free()`時点でlibcのチェックに引っかかり警告が出ています。

```
tex = malloc(sizeof(Texture*));
tex->texture = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Texture*));
tex->dst = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect*));
```

を

```
tex = malloc(sizeof(Texture));
tex->dst = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect));
```

とすると解決すると思います。

直接関係ありませんが追加でいくつか潜在的な問題があります。

- `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`はテクスチャを表す構造体のメモリを確保し返すので`tex->texture = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Texture*));`は不要です。
- dstやsrcをポインタとして扱う強い意図が無ければ、ポインタではなく `SDL_Rect dst; SDL_Rect src;` のほうが`tex = malloc(sizeof(Texture));`だけで済んで手軽です。
- 終了前に解放する使い方だけであれば問題ありませんが、一般には`Destroy(Texture* tex)`に`free(tex);`も必要です。